# I keep finding myself in the same error with TypeScript. What do I do when I need to return a type that will be known after execution?

Tags: javascript, typescript

For example: This throws an error

```
export const toArray = <T>(potentialArr: T): [T] =>
  kindOf(potentialArr) === 'array' ? potentialArr : [potentialArr];
```

Error

```
TS2322: Type 'T | [T]' is not assignable to type '[T]'.   Type 'T' is not assignable to type '[T]'.
```

But I know that this will always return an array, what am I doing wrong?
It makes no sense that TypeScript ignores the fact that I'm telling it that it will return an array.

No matter how I logically compose this, I can't seem to reason about the typing.

```
export const toArray = <T>(potentialArr: T | [T]): T | [T] =>
  kindOf(potentialArr) === 'array' ? potentialArr : [potentialArr];
```

This should work no?

but I get error

```
TS2322: Type 'T | [T | [T]]' is not assignable to type 'T | [T]'.   Type '[T | [T]]' is not assignable to type 'T | [T]'.     Type '[T | [T]]' is not assignable to type '[T]'.       Type 'T | [T]' is not assignable to type 'T'.         'T | [T]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.           Type '[T]' is not assignable to type 'T'.             '[T]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.
```

And then if I do this:

```
export const toArray = <T>(potentialArr: T): T | [T] =>
  kindOf(potentialArr) === 'array' ? potentialArr : [potentialArr];
```

It works with no error but then every value derived from this function is typed as either
x | [x]
Which isn't true because every value derived from this function is always [x]

same as this:

```
export const toArray = <T>(potentialArr: T) =>
  kindOf(potentialArr) === 'array' ? potentialArr : [potentialArr];
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Evert Updated, my bad

Comment: What is `kindOf` exactly?

Comment: @Evert kindOf is similar to tyoeof but it more precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution that builds without errors for me:

```
function foo<T>(input: [T] | T): [T] {
  return Array.isArray(input) ? input : [input];
}
```

If `kindOf` is not something typescript understands, you could still use it in this manner:

```
function isArray(input: any): input is any[] {
  return kindOf(input) === 'array';
}
```

But you're really just re-implementing the built-in `Array.isArray`, which is the more correct way to do this.

Comment: I see, my problem was the library I'm using. Is this an issue with the type defs of the lib?

Comment: I'm not sure that `kindof` can be implemented correctly with typescript in this way.. Generally I would also just suggest to avoid these kind of microlibraries. A little copy paste is better than a little dependency imho =)

Comment: Typescript can do these kind of type assertions with 'assertion functions', and 'type guards', but each of these tools can only give you yes/no answers and not broader such as 'This function can tell that a variable is array OR a string OR an object etc.`